# Spark MLlib classification input format using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

How can I **transform List of DTOs to Spark ML input dataset format**?

I have DTO:

```
public class MachineLearningDTO implements Serializable {
    private double label;
    private double[] features;

    public MachineLearningDTO() {
    }

    public MachineLearningDTO(double label, double[] features) {
        this.label = label;
        this.features = features;
    }

    public double getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(double label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public double[] getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(double[] features) {
        this.features = features;
    }
}
```

And code:

```
Dataset<MachineLearningDTO> mlInputDataSet = spark.createDataset(mlInputData, Encoders.bean(MachineLearningDTO.class));
LogisticRegression logisticRegression = new LogisticRegression();
LogisticRegressionModel model = logisticRegression.fit(MLUtils.convertMatrixColumnsToML(mlInputDataSet));
```

After execution of code I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column
>   features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7
>   but was actually ArrayType(DoubleType,false).

If change it to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT with code:

```
VectorUDT vectorUDT = new VectorUDT();
vectorUDT.serialize(Vectors.dense(......));
```

Then I am getting:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot infer type for class
>   org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT because it is not bean-compliant
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$serializerFor(JavaTypeInference.scala:437)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out, just in case someone also will stuck with it, I wrote simple converter and it works:

```
private Dataset<Row> convertToMlInputFormat(List< MachineLearningDTO> data) {
    List<Row> rowData = data.stream()
            .map(dto ->
                    RowFactory.create(dto.getLabel() ? 1.0d : 0.0d, Vectors.dense(dto.getFeatures())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("features", new VectorUDT(), false, Metadata.empty()),
    });

    return spark.createDataFrame(rowData, schema);
}
```